# Doctrine 2 Model: How set table name with "-" in it?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, name-conflict

How should I name a Doctrine 2 Model table row variable (e.g. `url-name` is the table row name) and I tried it with that:

```
/** @Column(name="url-name", type="string") */
private $urlName;

// or I tried also

/** @Column(name="`url-name`", type="string") */
private $url_name;
```

But it doesn't fetch the $urlName row (this row result is empty but other rows/the rest is fetched correct).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use minus character as a part of column name. Just take a look at this query:

```
SELECT url-name ...
```

It means substract name from url just like `price * tax` means multiply price by tax. Use `_` instead of `-`.

Comment: Why should I cannot use minus character as part of the column name? I have to set in in `\`\`` then it should work e.g. `SELECT \`url-name\` FROM ...` btw. see update in code above

Comment: I don't think its a doctrine problem... more like Crozin mentioned, it's just standard naming.. not to use characters like "* -", instead use "_" which should work just fine. Even if you put `` which is correct, if you execute the query the database engine will return an error

Comment: The only difference between `url_name`, `urlName` or `url-name` is its aesthetics. And yes, personally I also think that `url-name` looks prettier than `url_name` but the first form is just invalid. Using backquotes ('' in Oracle, [] in MSSQL etc.) is the worst workaround. Also... you're using Doctrine so what's the difference? You will probably always work on Doctrine schema using `urlName`.